# Laravel5.3 multi-domain auth

Tags: php, laravel, session, single-sign-on, laravel-5.3

- PHP 7.0.10-2
- nginx/1.10.0
- Laravel Framework version 5.3.6

---

Hey guys, I'm trying to make cross-domain auth with several laravel application.

In `config/session.php`:

```
'connection' => 'default',
...
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', '.baner-platform.local'),
```

*SESSION_DOMAIN is not set in .env, so it uses value from php config.*

In `.env`:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=redis

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

When I open domain and subdomain page in redis-cli I see 2 session keys:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "laravel:2GDEUYrVVIUhWbAG2PfaTQF5Hnotd6QYIvzG0Oo9"
2) "laravel:aNsivaryHAGm7TYXEIkofHGVWkJYCCdwdtczyjUn"
```

*When im loggin on domain and refresh page on subdomain it loose session on domain and conversely.*

For both applications I use one DB and one common model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly!

By default all laravel cookies are encrypted by midlware `\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class`

so I've add session cookie to $except array:
**\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies**

```
 protected $except = [
        'laravel_session'
    ];
```